# How to set menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

```
/*My header menu code*/

$args = array(
    'theme-location' => 'primary'
);
wp_nav_menu($args);

/*My footer menu code*/
$args = array(
    'theme-location' => 'footer'
);
wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

**My functions.php file**

```
register_nav_menus(
array(
    'primary' => __('Main Primary Menu'),
    'footer'=> __('Footer Menu'),
    )
);
```

when I select different menus for header and footer, it gives priority to the footer menu and set footer menu in the header also but when I delete footer menu then it sets menu which I selected for the header, what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

**use below code**

```
/*My header menu code*/

$header_args = array(
  'theme-location' => 'primary'
);
wp_nav_menu($header_args);

/*My footer menu code*/
$footer_args = array(
  'theme-location' => 'footer'
);
wp_nav_menu($footer_args);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.